# How to use a function in another function in same class using PHP

Tags: php, class, geolocation

I have a class with the name of `assets` and in the `assets` class there were many functions that exist but some functions didn't work as I expected.

**Here's my code**

```
<?php
class assets
{
    function curl_get_contents($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    
        return $data;
    }

    function get_client_ip()
    {
        $ipaddress = '';
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        } else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        } else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])) {
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
        } else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        } else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])) {
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
        } else if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        } else {
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
        }
    
        return $ipaddress;
    }

    function getCountry($ip){
        $PublicIP = $this->get_client_ip();
        $json = $this->curl_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/".$PublicIP."/geo");
        $json =json_decode($json, true);
        $country  = $json['country'];
        return $country;
    }

    function getRegion($ip){
        $PublicIP = $this->get_client_ip();
        $json = $this->curl_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/$PublicIP/geo");
        $json =json_decode($json, true);
        $region   = $json['region'];
        return $region;
    }

    function getCity($ip){
        $PublicIP = $this->get_client_ip();
        $json = $this->curl_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/$PublicIP/geo");
        $json =json_decode($json, true);
        $city = $json['city'];
        return $city;
    }
}

$assets = new assets();
$ip = $assets->get_client_ip();
echo($ip);
$city = $assets->getCountry($ip);
?>
```

**Output**

> `abc.pq.wx.yz`
> `// no output for country`

I write this output into this form for security purposes but the IP address is correct

This code gave me only the IP address but this code didn't give the county region and city. When I tried to call this [`Api`](http://ipinfo.io/) manually I was getting results as I expected.

Comment: And `return` is commented in the function. What do you expect then?

Comment: @u_mulder sorry but `return` isn't commented on real code and `By mistake` I commented `return` on post

Comment: _Side note:_ Instead of making multiple identical requests to the API, call it once and reuse the same response instead. Every call comes with overhead.

Comment: `$city = $assets->getCountry($ip);` Slightly illogical! And you dont output `$city` ?? Like `echo $city;`

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you for very much to remind me my mistake

Comment: SO is a Q&A site. That means posts should keep their format for a Q and Answers. Please don't mix the answer and the question posts, don't put 'solved', etc..

Answer (score 2):

In your `getCountry()` function you have returned the value, But you still didn't print it.

```php
function getCountry($ip){
    $PublicIP = $this->get_client_ip();
    $json = $this->curl_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/".$PublicIP."/geo");
    $json =json_decode($json, true);
    $country  = $json['country'];
    retun $country;
}
```

```php
$city = $assets->getCountry($ip);
echo $city;
```

**NOTE**

Why you are passing `$ip` into `getCountry()` if you are not using it in the implementation?